# Running "spark-class org.apache.spark.deploy.master.Master" doesn't return anything on cygwin

Tags: apache-spark

I followed the instructions given in the spark-standalone manual for windows but on executing `spark-class org.apache.spark.deploy.master.Master` returns nothing. I'm using `cygwin`.
In the `spark-env.sh`, I edited the following:

```
export SPARK_MASTER_IP "localhost"
```

Yet it returns nothing. How do I make it work?

I also tried:

```
export SPARK_MASTER_IP = "<my_public_ip>" #mentioned my public IP here
```

But this threw an error:

> $ spark-class org.apache.spark.deploy.master.Master
>   C:\Spark\spark-1.6.1-bin-hadoop2.4/conf/spark-env.sh: line 49: export:
>   `=': not a valid identifier
>   C:\Spark\spark-1.6.1-bin-hadoop2.4/conf/spark-env.sh: line 49: export:
>   `my_public_ip': not a valid identifier

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
export SPARK_MASTER_HOST=localhost
```

But why do you use Cygwin?

Comment: Even this didn't return anything. I still can't figure out why it's not returning anything. The reason I use Cygwin is cause I want to make use of unix commands.